# Cast to Date failed for value with mongoose and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I think i'm going insane, i just can't make it works...

The Schema is defined like this

```js
const ChildSchema = new Schema({
  birthDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Then i have the parent defined like this

```js
const ParentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    children: {
      type: [ChildSchema]
    }
  }
);
```

I'd like to create a static methods for getting children born today like this

```js
ParentSchema.statics.findTodayChildren = async function findTodayChildren(
  parentId
) {
  const today = new Date(2019, 11, 16); // Hard coded for debugging
  const query = await this.find({
    _id: parentId,
    children: {
      birthDate: {
        $lte: today
      }
    }
  }).select("children");

  console.log(query[0].children);
};
```

I forced the query to return something but i keep getting this frustrating error `Cast to date failed for value`. The funny thing is that i remove the `$lte` filter and use a simple `birthDate: today` it works (obviously the array is empty because matching a date with timestamp it's not as easy).

I also checked in mongoDb if i was storing correctly the data and it says it's a Date value

```
_id: 32vdsks09i209isdljivlk,
birthDate: 2019-10-14T14:24:35.000+00:00
```

I've tried every single Javascript method, but nothing seems to works

```js
$lte: new Date()
$lte: new Date().toISOString()
$lte: new Date().toGMTString()
```

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
  const query = await this.find({
    _id: parentId,
    'children.birthDate': {
      $lte: today
    }
  }).select("children");
```

Read more about it [here in docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#specify-equality-match-on-a-nested-field).